# being up to one's job meaning

Tags: meaning

"Like all men not really up to their job, he was a stickler for externals and petty quotidian things; and in lieu of an intellect he had accumulated an armoury of capitalized key-words like Discipline and Tradition and Responsibility." The Magus by John Fowles

What does "really up to their job" mean in this sentence?

Comment: ***Be up to***. Be able to do or deal with. This usage is often put negatively, that is, not be up to something. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To be up to a job" means to be able, qualified, and willing to perform the job.  So the man in question isn't really qualified to do the work assigned, so he instead he focuses on the irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to basic on-the-job competence. The excerpt is asserting the popular belief that people that lack technical competence in their job function will compensate by using buzzwords, posturing and engaging in ultimately pointless busy-work